# Assistance on a SQL Query - The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a sub-select and Inner Join in the same query, with little success.

The query, as it stands is below, and returning the error

> The multi-part identifier
>   "Company.LocalityId" could not be
>   bound.

```
UPDATE Company
SET
    Company.BusinessRegionId = b.Id
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        Id
      FROM
        BusinessRegion
      WHERE
        tag = 'Australia/New South Wales'
) b
INNER JOIN Locality l ON 
    Company.LocalityId = l.Id
where 
    l.StateOrProvinceAbbreviation = 'NSW'
```

Any assistance would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your BusinessRegion and Locality tables aren't really joined at all in that query, right? Can you do something like this instead?

```
UPDATE Company
SET BusinessRegionId = (
    SELECT TOP 1 Id
    FROM BusinessRegion
    WHERE Tag = 'Australia/New South Wales')
FROM Locality l
WHERE l.Id = LocalityId AND l.StateOrProvinceAbbreviation = 'NSW'
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, I was getting a little too verbose :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variation of the query:

```
UPDATE 
   c
SET
    c.BusinessRegionId = 
    (
      SELECT TOP 1
        Id
      FROM
        BusinessRegion
      WHERE
        tag = 'Australia/New South Wales'
    )
FROM 
   Company c
   INNER JOIN Locality l ON c.LocalityId = l.Id
WHERE
    l.StateOrProvinceAbbreviation = 'NSW'
```

Comment: I actually went for this one myself (easier for seeing what was going on in the join), but it was Matt's suggestion that got me over the line